# How do I use SVG icons in HTML?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an svg file with 3 icons.

When I import it via the `<img>` tag, I get the 3 icons one below each other.
I want to use the icons in a row, one next to the other.
How can I use them separately?

The .svg file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="16.3px"
     height="26.9px" viewBox="0 0 16.3 26.9" enable-background="new 0 0 16.3 26.9" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="bg">
</g>
<g id="ui">
    <g>
        <polygon points="8.1,0 10.3,4.3 15.2,5 11.7,8.3 12.5,13 8.1,10.8 3.8,13 4.6,8.3 1.1,5 6,4.3         "/>
        <polygon fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="8.1,13 10.3,17.3 15.2,18 11.7,21.3 12.5,26 8.1,23.8 
            3.8,26 4.6,21.3 1.1,18 6,17.3       "/>
    </g>
</g>
<g id="pop_ups">
</g>
</svg>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Put each of the icons in their own `<svg>` element.

Comment: What do you mean? How can I know their names?

Comment: Edited my question. I want to access one of the Icons in the svg file.

Comment: The SVG you posted contains two stars.  You mention 3 icons... Are we looking at the right code?

Comment: I have 2 svg files. This one is 2 icons. I just want to know how to use it.

Answer (score 8):

Use the SVG file as a sprite.

Create an icon-sized element, hiding the overflow:

```css
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16.3px;
  height: 13.45px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Position the SVG within the element so the icon shows through:

```css
.icon > img {
    position: relative;
}
.darkStar > img {
    top: 0;
}
.lightStar > img {
    top: -13.45px;
}
```

Demo (using inline SVG instead of a linked `<img>`, which defeats the purpose, but is easier to demo here):

```css
.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16.3px;
    height: 13.45px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.icon > svg {
    position: relative;
}
.darkStar > svg {
    top: 0;
}
.lightStar > svg {
    top: -13.45px;
}
```

```html
<span class="icon lightStar">
    <svg width="16.3px" height="26.9px">
        <polygon points="8.1,0 10.3,4.3 15.2,5 11.7,8.3 12.5,13 8.1,10.8 3.8,13 4.6,8.3 1.1,5 6,4.3" />
        <polygon points="8.1,13 10.3,17.3 15.2,18 11.7,21.3 12.5,26 8.1,23.8 3.8,26 4.6,21.3 1.1,18 6,17.3" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
    </svg>
</span>
<span class="icon darkStar">
    <svg width="16.3px" height="26.9px">
        <polygon points="8.1,0 10.3,4.3 15.2,5 11.7,8.3 12.5,13 8.1,10.8 3.8,13 4.6,8.3 1.1,5 6,4.3" />
        <polygon points="8.1,13 10.3,17.3 15.2,18 11.7,21.3 12.5,26 8.1,23.8 3.8,26 4.6,21.3 1.1,18 6,17.3" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
    </svg>
</span>
```

Comment: Why can't you add the `svg` as `background-image` to the `.icon` class in `css`? Wouldn't it be easier that way?

Comment: @gen - Yes, you could do that. And yes, there are advantages to using a CSS-only approach.

Comment: thank you for confirming, I have little relevant background here so I was just guessing

Answer (score 4):

You can use **fragment identifiers** to display only part of the SVG file in any particular `img` element.

The advantage of this approach is that the "individual sprites" in your SVG file are defined *in your SVG file*, so when using it elsewhere you don't need to know anything of the internal structure, you can just ask for what you want by name:

```
<button>
  <img src="x.svg#star1" alt="*">
</button>
```

The most cross-platform-compatible solution is add some SVG `view`s which define which part of the image to show for which ID fragment. The view syntax is similar to the global `viewBox` attribute of the root `SVG` element*:

```
<view id="star1" viewBox="0 0 10 10"/>
```

Here's a [good blog post](http://www.broken-links.com/2012/08/14/better-svg-sprites-with-fragment-identifiers/) (with [a live example](http://www.broken-links.com/tests/svg/fragment-identifiers.php)) which explains the technique in great detail.

<sub>*note that I haven't calculated that `viewBox` value for your SVG, you'll have to figure it out yourself.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you mean vertically or horizontally, but here's something I found from Codepen.io which has a lot of SVG samples you might want to go through.

http://codepen.io/jonnowitts/pen/waONVV

Here he has SVG's lined up vertically in a row.

```
  <button type="button" id="positive">
    <div class="content">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="42" viewBox="-9 0 38 40" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <path class="check" fill="none" d="M0 20 L8 28 L25 10" stroke="white" stroke-width="3"/>
      </svg>
      <span>Positive</span>
    </div>
  </button>
  <button id="negative">
    <div class="content">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="42" viewBox="-9 0 38 40" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <path class="cross-1" fill="none" d="M0 10 L20 30" stroke="white" stroke-width="3"/>
        <path class="cross-2" fill="none" d="M20 10 L0 30" stroke="white" stroke-width="3"/>
      </svg>
      <span>Negative</span>
    </div>
  </button>

  <button id="warning">
    <div class="content">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="42" viewBox="-3 0 38 40" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <polygon class="triangle"
                 stroke="white"
                 stroke-width="2"
                 fill="none"
                 points="15,4 0,34 30,34"
                 />
        <path class="exclaim-1" d="M15 14 L15 22 Z" stroke-width="4" stroke="white" fill="none" />
        <path class="exclaim-2" d="M15 24 L15 29 Z" stroke-width="4" stroke="white" fill="none" />
      </svg>
      <span>Warning</span>
    </div>
  </button>
```